# Generating functions (parts equal to $2$)

Tags: combinatorics, integers, integer-partitions

What is the generating function for partitions into parts equal to $2, 5$ or $7$?

I know the function of distinct parts, but what if they don't have to be distinct?

Comment: To be perfectly clear, what partitions of $14$ exist for you?  $7+7,~7+5+2,5+5+2+2$ sure, but do you consider $2+5+7$ or any of the four other ways to order them to be different than $7+5+2$?

Comment: Assuming that you do intend to use the term partitions and order doesn't matter, e.g. $7+5+2$ is considered the same as $2+5+7$ (*as opposed to compositions where they would have been considered different*), consider using building blocks of the form $(1+x^k+x^{2k}+x^{3k}+\dots)$ for appropriate choices of $k$ and an appropriate method of combining said building blocks together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(1+x^2+x^4+x^6+\cdots)(1+x^5+x^{10}+x^{15}+\cdots)(1+x^7+x^{14}+x^{21}+\cdots)$$
which I'll leave you to simplify.